Uploading dags on Airflow-EKS
Today I have a question
In resume, I have an EKS cluster and I installed Apache Airflow in it.
I decided to create the PV and PVC to maintain the Dags instead of locally in web pod.
The definition is
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: airflow-dags-pv
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: gp3-storage-class
  hostPath:
    path: /mnt/data/airflow/dags


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: airflow-dags-pvc
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: gp3-storage-class

Then I installed Airflow with Helm
helm install my-airflow apache-airflow/airflow \
  --set dags.persistence.enabled=true \
  --set dags.persistence.existingClaim=airflow-dags-pvc \
  --set airflow.config.AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER=/opt/airflow/dags

Finally I copied my dag.py from local into my web pod.
At the beginning the dag never appeared, but when I entered to the pod to verify if the copy was correct in path 'opt/airflow/dags/' I saw my dag.py but in UI it never appeared.
I restarted the pod and then when I entered again into my pod the dag had disappeared although when I installed with helm I specified to use an existent pvc.
Can someone help me if I'm wrong or how can I upload dags into Airflow in EKS using pvc?

It seems you are missing to link your PVC to your PV, unless you are using Dynamic provisionning in this case you can ommit the PV section in PVC and the PV manifest.
in static provisionning you need to link your PVC to your PV like this :
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: airflow-dags-pvc
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: gp3-storage-class
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  volumeName: airflow-dags-pv

Check k8s docs for differences between static and dynamic provisionning.
Hope this help
